# Setting Timer For Online Quiz

Tags: javascript, php, timer

I'm trying to build an online quiz, I've done most of it - questions get selected randomly
from database one at a time, user enters/selects an answer, there is a response, another random question
pops up - I've done all that, the tricky aspect is how to attach a timer(Javascript, I guess) to the instance the question pops up and when a response is entered...any general guideline on how to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I will give you an approach on how I would go about creating a timer of any sorts for every question. I would prefer using a javascript only timer employing the `setInterval()` method because it's pretty easy to implement. I've given a sample snippet that just starts counting from 0 every second. You can modify it into a countdown timer to suit your needs. [Relevant documentation](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp) on timing events in JS.

```js
var myVar = setInterval(function() {
  myTimer()
}, 1000);
var d = 0;

function myTimer() {
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = d++;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

  <p>A script on this page starts a timer:</p>

  <p id="demo"></p>
</body>

</html>
```

A thing to keep in mind while developing a javascript timer is to account for browser refreshes. You would want to keep tabs on the 'state' of the timer if the user accidently hits refresh or loses internet connectivity. If you are using javascript, you might want to try [local Storage](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp) built into the browser for storing this value. So at any point in time you would have something like this:

```
 // Store
  localStorage.setItem("lastTime", d); //In context of my code snippet
 // Retrieve
 var lastTime = localStorage.getItem("lastTime");
```

So you can keep track of accidental glitches while attempting a question and correctly account for the total time for that question. You can then save these times per question into a database or make a request to a `php` script that does the necessary compiling and reporting of the whole quiz but that again largely depends on your implementation.

If however you want to implement this whole thing in PHP, then you might want to check out using [cookies](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_cookies.asp) or [session](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp) variables for storing the time elapsed per question for a specific user.

I hope this gets you started in the right direction.

Comment: @bodesam, please accept the answer if it worked so that others in a similar problem would also benefit out of this. Thanks.

Comment: Definitely, still trying to figure out how to read the time as contained in <p id="demo"></p> with php

Answer (score 0):

Self timer,when you want to start a new Exam :

```
request.getSession().setAttribute("totalNumberOfQuizQuestions",document.getElementsByTagName("totalQuizQuestions").item(0).getTextContent());
request.getSession().setAttribute("quizDuration",document.getElementsByTagName("quizDuration").item(0).getTextContent());
request.getSession().setAttribute("min",document.getElementsByTagName("quizDuration").item(0).getTextContent());
request.getSession().setAttribute("sec",0);
```